# Using ror and rol on a register with a variable in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, encryption, x86, intel

I tried to make an encryption/decryption program in assembly. It's working fine, but I must input manually the number of bits for ror and rol. I wonder if I can do something like ror eax,n , where n is my variable, between 1 and 7, readed from keyboard. How can I do that ? Thank you. Here's my code.

```
 .data
 tfile1 db "text.txt", 0
 read db "rb", 0
 write db "wb",0
 format db "%c", 0
  msg1 DB "n=",0
 n DD 0
 formatd DB "%d",0
 buffer db 0

 .code
 start:
 push offset msg1           ; put msg1 on stack
 call printf            ; print msg1
 add esp,4           ; clear stack
 push offset n           ; put n on stack
 push offset formatd           ; put n format on stack
 call scanf           ; write n value
 add esp,8           ; clear stack
 mov ebx,n           ; copy n in ebx
 push ebx           ; put n on stack
 push offset formatd           ; put n format on stack 
 add esp,8           ; clear stack
 push offset read           ;put read binary operation on stack
 push offset tfile1           ;put text.txt on stack
 call fopen           ;open text.txt
 add ESP, 8           ;clear stack
 mov esi, eax           ;save pointer to the stack
 push esi           ;stream
 push 1           ;count
 push 1           ;size
 push offset buffer
 read_loop:
 call fread  
 test eax,eax           ;check if eax=0
 jz close_tfile
 xor eax, eax           ;clear eax 
 mov al, buffer           ; copy buffer in al
 not eax            ;1's complement
 add eax,1           ; 2's complement
 ror eax,3 ; ror eax with 3 ! Here's my problem I wana imput the bytes value
 rol eax,3 ; rol eax with 3 ! Here's my problem I wana imput the bytes value
 not eax           ;  2's complement
 add eax,1           ; 1's complement
 push eax           ; put eax on stack
 push offset format           ; put format on stack
 call printf           ; print from text.txt
 add esp, 8           ;clear stack
 jmp read_loop
 close_tfile:
 add esp, 16           ; clear stack from fread
 push esi ;stream    
 call fclose
 add esp,4 
 push 0
 call exit
```

end start

Comment: You can use CL (any only CL) as the second operand instead of an immediate operand.

Comment: You can shift by three bits as your code seems to want with `mov cl,3; ror eax,cl; rol eax,cl` but that will leave `eax` in exactly the same state. It's unclear what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Thank you! If I use CL it's working .  @WeatherVane   This was my problem:   Encryption
-> take every ASCII character from the text file and make the 2's complement
-> ROR the value with a key C (between 0 and 7)

Decryption
-> do the reverse for decryption

Comment: You do realize that you're creating a simple substitution cipher that's easily cracked?

Comment: @RossRidge I know man . I'm terrible at assembly.I just try to learn a little that's all, anyway  thank you for your tip.